# How to use the Meego touch theme

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, themes, meego

I'm new to QT and Meego. I would like to know how to make use of Meego touch theme. I have already cloned the source for it from  git://gitorious.org/meego-handset-ux/meegotouch-theme-meego.git .

I don't see anything helpful though on how to use it. 
Can somebody give me a jumpstart or at least tell me how to make use of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MeeGo themes are used by the MeeGoTouch library (which is built on-top of the QGraphicsView/Scene framework), see at http://meego.gitorious.org/meegotouch/libmeegotouch

The latest API docs for the whole stuff are at:
http://apidocs.meego.com/git-tip/mtf/

Styling specifics e.g. at http://apidocs.meego.com/git-tip/mtf/styling.html

Answer (score 2):

Like Steffen mentioned, the theme you are referring is intended for meegotouch  library which runs on top of standard qt. So in order to use it, you need to get meegotouch first and write the application with meegotouch specific widgets.

However, there's a qt plugin that enables standard qt applications to look like meegotouch applications. Code here: http://meego.gitorious.org/meegotouch/meegotouch-qt-style